# Reactjs fetch and show data directly

Tags: reactjs, fetch

Is there anyway or example to make fetch and show data directly.

Say we have `JSON` data and we want to show once some data available so if there many objects in the `JSON` and once one data object is ready we show it and wait until next once and load once ready as well. We do this all in one endpoint.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

What your describing is pretty standard in React.

Say you have your `List` component, and when the component mounts you watch to make a `fetch` to your API and render the data. You could do something like the below.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'

export default class List extends Component {
   state = { 
      listData: []
   }

   componentDidMount = () =>{
     fetch('YOUR_URL_HERE')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => this.setState({ listData: data}));
   }

   render(){
     return(
        <div>
          {this.state.listData.map((listItem, i)=>{
               return <p>{listItem.propertyToRender}</p>
           })}
         </div>
     )
   }
}
```